# How to access IEEE Xplore on Lynx browser?

Tags: linux, command-line, lynx

I tried to access a paper via Lynx as follows-

`lynx http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=5495638`

I've sshed in to my college PC where we have IEEE subscription (Also I have set the proxy setting in lynx correctly). I allowed all the cookies as `Y`. But lynx is giving following error

```
   Error 500--Internal Server Error

   From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:

   10.5.1 500 Internal Server Error

   The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.
```

Please help.

Comment: Works great for me; I get a login form.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKjörling. You mean when you access just their main website or a link to specific paper (like I had given example). Also when we use it from college it doesnt give login form, we are "auto" logged-in via institute subscription.

Comment: I did `lynx http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=5495638`, copying the URL from your post, and accepted all cookies. There isn't much else one can do from the outside to reproduce the problem, and I certainly didn't get any HTTP 500 response.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling sorry for misunderstanding. I am not sure how to reproduce it somewhere else. It works via Firefox on a PC in college lan (a friend had tried just now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. It was a problem with proxy network in my area.